# How to forward http/https request to socks5 in node js

Tags: node.js, rest, nginx, proxy, socks

The initial problem is [nginx proxy_pass with a socks5 proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884353/nginx-proxy-pass-with-a-socks5-proxy)

I decided to proxy_pass to localhost with node js server. So then I need to somehow convert http/https requests to socksv5.

I have very simple node js server let's it handle simple get and post requests like

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    // need to forward via socks5
});

app.post('/', function(req,res) {
    // need to forward via socks5
});

app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log("Started on PORT 3000");
})
```

There are some libraries like https://www.npmjs.com/package/socks or https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-https-client but it can only do get requests and also without handle 301 redirect response.

It seems that it's very easy and simple task but I still can not find the turnkey solution. Is there some or at least some good libraries to convert post and get (put, delete) to socks5?